# How do I preview in composing?

Tags: compositing-nodes

[image]

I'm watching a lecture.
When a YouTuber added and changed nodes in composing, the image below changed according to that.
How do I get a real-time rendering image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main window is the *Compositor*, and not visible in the screenshot there must be a *Viewer Node* to the right. *Backdrop* is disabled, so you don't see the composite behind the nodes.

In the bottom left corner is the *UV/Image Editor* and below your red frame you can see that the display is set to *Viewer Node* instead of the default *Render Result*.

So everything changing in the *Compositor* which you normally watch in the backdrop is displayed in the *Image Editor*.

Comment: I thought about what it was after seeing the editor type icon, but I didn't know it at all, thank you for letting me know.

Comment: Just click the icon next to new and open, and click the render result.